# Typescript argument type errors when using generic but hard coding possible values from the generic does not

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a simple mapper function to convert values of a specific type to another type. Here's what I have

```js
const profiles = {
    string: {
        date: (string: string): Date => new Date,
    },
    date: {
        string: (date: Date): string => date.toISOString()
    }
}

type Profiles = typeof profiles
type mappers<T extends keyof Profiles> = Profiles[T][keyof Profiles[T]]

function map<T extends keyof Profiles>(type: T, source: Parameters<mappers<T>>[0], destination: keyof Profiles[T]) {
    
}
```

In the type for the argument `source` its using the generic `T`. And it errors saying

```
Type '{ string: { date: (string: string) => Date; }; date: { string: (date: Date) => string; }; }[T][string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
```

But if I hover over `T` it has the type `"string" | "date"` and if I hard code either of those values in place of `T` it works as I would expect. It even catches if I use something other than `"string" | "date"` as I would expect.

So why does it work with the values that `T` can be but not with `T` itself?

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5e4VN) (thanks [@md2perpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412534/md2perpe))

Comment: [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N5e4VN)

Comment: The compiler just isn't smart enough to do the higher order analysis to know that `Mappers<K>` will be function-like no matter what `K` is. It leaves it mostly deferred and then complains.  Does that address your question?  Are you also asking how to work around it?  You can do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDkPVw) where you give the compiler a hint.  Let me know if that works for you as an answer or if I'm missing something.

Comment: using `Extract` does work! Very clever. Please add that as an answer so I can accept it